# Visual Studio/C# code similar to #pragma mark in Xcode

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, visual-studio, pragma

Is there a code snippet in Visual Studio/C# similar to Xcode's `#pragma mark` directive?

E.g. When setting `#pragma mark Some Part Of Code` in Xcode, "Some Part Of Code" appears in bold in the method enumeration drop-down list, thus you can use it for grouping methods according to their functionality and finding them easier later when needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`#region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?

Else, C# has [`#pragma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x74w198a.aspx) too, but from your description it sounds like you want region

Comment: #region is definitely a way to group code, and I use it in my apps, however, it is different in function from #pragma. If regions would also appear in the method drop-down list, so I can easily access certain parts of code/methods, then that would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: In response to Ron, #region allows you to collapse code in the main editor. This is far different than what #pragma mark does (I'm also looking for this functionality and frankly, #region is a poor substitute). What #pragma does is put a bold, user defined name in the enumeration drop-down list. #region does not.

Comment: Is there anything available in C# like the #pragma mark in Objective C or #MARK introduced in Swift which actually allows to group functions together and displays it in bold in the function list drop down? #region is not a substitute to that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in C# with Xamarin Studio,

> Go To:
>
> Xamarin preferences --> Text editor --> General --> Then Enable Code
>   folding

Then you can use,

```
#region SomeRegion

//...Group of code...

#endregion            // end of MyRegion
```